# Resolving Error Code: 1005. Can't create table '' (errno: 150) Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I am creating following three tables in mysql

> 1. POSTMASTER
> 2. ADVERTISEMENT
> 3. CANDIDATEMAIN

Here are the create statements

> POSTMASTER

```
CREATE TABLE `postmaster` (
  `POSTCODE` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `POSTNAME` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`POSTCODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

> ADVERTISEMENT

```
CREATE TABLE `advertisment` (
  `ADVTNO` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `ADVTDATE` date NOT NULL,
  `POSTCODE` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `ADVTOPENDATE` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'ADVERTISEMENT OPENING DATE',
  `ADVTCLOSEDATE` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'ADVERTISEMENT CLOSING DATE',
  `EDITCLOSEDATE` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'CLOSING DATE FOR EDITING APPLICATION',
  `LASTREPRINTDATE` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'LAST DATE FOR REPRINTING APPLICATION',
  `FEESCST` int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FEE FOR SC/ST CATEGORY',
  `FEESTAFF` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FEE FOR STAFF ',
  `FEEOBC` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FEE FOR OBC CATEGORY',
  `ADVOCATEEXPERIENCE` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ADVTNO`,`ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`),
  KEY `fk_post` (`POSTCODE`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_post` FOREIGN KEY (`POSTCODE`) REFERENCES `postmaster` (`POSTCODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Everything till here is fine but when I go for creation of the **`CANDIDATEMAIN`** table I get error

> Here is the create statement of **CANDIDATEMAIN**

```
CREATE TABLE `candidatemain` (

  `ADVTNO` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ADVTDATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `POSTCODE` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `REGISTRATIONNO` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SALUTATION` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `FULLNAME` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `SURNAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LASTNAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LASTUPDATEDIP` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `LASTUPDATEDDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTRYDATE` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ADVTNO`,`ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`,`REGISTRATIONNO`),
  KEY `FK_ADVT` (`ADVTNO`, `ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ADVT` FOREIGN KEY (`ADVTNO`, `ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`) REFERENCES `advertisment` (`ADVTNO`, `ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The Error I get is :

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'dbName.candidatemain' (errno: 150)
```

What could be the reason for this error?

> MYSql Verion: **mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.53, for Win64**

Comment: The problem is with your constraint, as per: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html saying: ***"1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE) Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed."***

Comment: is the table name `advertisment` intentionally mistaken?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Create `advertisment` table with default charset as `utf8`;**

*latin1* columns are not equivalent to *utf8* columns. So foreign key constraint can not form correctly. Hence the `1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)` error.

Here is my mysql log.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `advertisment` (
    ->   `ADVTNO` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
    ->   `ADVTDATE` date NOT NULL,
    ->   `POSTCODE` int(2) NOT NULL,
    ->   `ADVTOPENDATE` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'ADVERTISEMENT OPENING DATE',
    ->   `ADVTCLOSEDATE` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'ADVERTISEMENT CLOSING DATE',
    ->   `EDITCLOSEDATE` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'CLOSING DATE FOR EDITING APPLICATION',
    ->   `LASTREPRINTDATE` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'LAST DATE FOR REPRINTING APPLICATION',
    ->   `FEESCST` int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FEE FOR SC/ST CATEGORY',
    ->   `FEESTAFF` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FEE FOR STAFF ',
    ->   `FEEOBC` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FEE FOR OBC CATEGORY',
    ->   `ADVOCATEEXPERIENCE` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`ADVTNO`,`ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`),
    ->   KEY `fk_post` (`POSTCODE`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `fk_post` FOREIGN KEY (`POSTCODE`) REFERENCES `postmaster` (`POSTCODE`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; -- <== This little change make it work.
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `candidatemain` (
    ->
    ->   `ADVTNO` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `ADVTDATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    ->   `POSTCODE` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `REGISTRATIONNO` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `SALUTATION` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    ->   `FULLNAME` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
    ->   `SURNAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ->   `LASTNAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `LASTUPDATEDIP` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `LASTUPDATEDDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `ENTRYDATE` date NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`ADVTNO`,`ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`,`REGISTRATIONNO`),
    ->   KEY `FK_ADVT` (`ADVTNO`, `ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`) ,
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_ADVT` FOREIGN KEY (`ADVTNO`, `ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`) REFERENCES `advertisment ` (`ADVTNO`, `ADVTDATE`,`POSTCODE`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you tell me how you we able to find out the mistake... I mean is there any specific software that could exactly point out the mistake.. because the `error 1005` gives a very vague picture of the error... Thanks again!!!

Comment: Dunno. Just scanned through your SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

Your `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` for table `candidatemain` and `advertisment` has different charset, this causes the error, let them have same charset.